# Can git do a diff between a repo file and an external (non-repo) file?

Tags: git, version-control, diff, git-diff

I need to do a diff between the version of `myfile` that was in `master~2`, and a copy of `myfile` that exists outside the repository itself (say `D:\folder\myfile`).

The wording in `git-diff` under `--no-index` says:

> git diff --no-index [--options] [--] […]
>
> This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can omit the --no-index option when running the command in a working
>   tree controlled by Git and **at least one of the paths points outside
>   the working tree**

The wording "at least one" seems to imply that comparison can be done between one repo file and one non-repo file, but in practice:

> ```
> $ git diff master~2:myfile D:/folder/myfile  
> error: Could not access: 'master~2:myfile'
>
> $ git diff master~2:myfile -- D:/folder/myfile  
> fatal: D:/folder/myfile: 'D:/folder/myfile' is outside repository  
>
> $ git diff --no-index master~2:myfile -- D:/folder/myfile  
> usage: git diff --no-index <path> <path>
> ```

What is the easiest way to achieve this comparison?

Comment: Your `master~2:myfile` does not meet the stated criterion of "given *two paths on the filesystem*". I believe that is intending to state that you could do `git diff myfile /path/to/otherfile`, where one file is in your working directory and one isn't, not that one of them can be a general blob refspec that needs to be pulled from your object store...

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense, thanks @twalberg. A lesson in careful reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using `git-diff`, I found an indirect way of achieving this - the method given in [this blog post](http://flaviusim.com/blog/view-old-git-version-of-a-file-in-a-vim-split/), just using the external file as the original "current file", and making sure to have the repo directory as current-directory before doing the `git show`.

The steps involved are:

1. Open the external non-repo file in vim the usual way
2. Do a `:vsp new` to vertically split a new (blank) window
3. `:cd` to the working directory of the git repository
4. `:read !git show master~2:myfile` to read the contents of myfile as it was 2 commits ago
5. `setf yourfiletypehere` for syntax highlighting (optional)
6. `:diffthis` in one window, then switch to the other window and run `:diffthis` again, and you have your diff

Comment: It sounds similar to what I did, just storing the "versioned" file somewhere and launching comparison on it, but in a single line like `git show master~2:myfile > ~/tmp/myfile; git diff -- ~/tmp/myfile ~/secondFolder/myfile`. I really like that vi trick, though.